# Jaggy paths when blitting an offscreen CGLayer to the current context

Tags: performance, core-graphics, antialiasing, cglayer, blit

In my current project I need to draw a complex background as a background for a few UITableView cells. Since the code for drawing this background is pretty long and CPU heavy when executed in the cell's drawRect: method, I decided to render it only once to a CGLayer and then blit it to the cell to enhance the overall performance.

The code I'm using to draw the background to a CGLayer:

```
+ (CGLayerRef)standardCellBackgroundLayer
{
    static CGLayerRef standardCellBackgroundLayer;

    if(standardCellBackgroundLayer == NULL)
    {
        CGContextRef viewContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width, PLACES_DEFAULT_CELL_HEIGHT);

        standardCellBackgroundLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(viewContext, rect.size, NULL);
        CGContextRef context = CGLayerGetContext(standardCellBackgroundLayer);

        // Setup the paths
        CGRect rectForShadowPadding = CGRectInset(rect, (PLACES_DEFAULT_CELL_SHADOW_SIZE / 2) + PLACES_DEFAULT_CELL_SIDE_PADDING, (PLACES_DEFAULT_CELL_SHADOW_SIZE / 2));
        CGMutablePathRef path = createPathForRoundedRect(rectForShadowPadding, LIST_ITEM_CORNER_RADIUS);

        // Save the graphics context state
        CGContextSaveGState(context);

        // Draw shadow
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), PLACES_DEFAULT_CELL_SHADOW_SIZE, [Skin shadowColor]);
        CGContextAddPath(context, path);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [Skin whiteColor]);
        CGContextFillPath(context);

        // Clip for gradient
        CGContextAddPath(context, path);
        CGContextClip(context);

        // Draw gradient on clipped path
        CGPoint startPoint = rectForShadowPadding.origin;
        CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(rectForShadowPadding.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(rectForShadowPadding));
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, [Skin listGradient], startPoint, endPoint, 0);

        // Restore the graphics state and release everything
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        CGPathRelease(path);
    }

    return standardCellBackgroundLayer;
}
```

The code to blit the layer to the current context:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(context, CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), [Skin standardCellBackgroundLayer]);
}
```

This actually does the trick pretty nice but the only problem I'm having is that the rounded corners (check the static method). Are very jaggy when blitted to the screen. This wasn't the case when the drawing code was at its original position: in the drawRect method.

How do I get back this antialiassing?

For some reason the following methods don't have any impact on the anti-aliassing:

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by just using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and setting the scale to `0.0`.

Sorry for awakening an old post, but I came across it so someone else may too. More details can be found in the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions):

> If you specify a value of `0.0`, the scale factor is set to the scale
>   factor of the device’s main screen.

Basically meaning that if it's a retina display it will create a retina context, that way you can specify `0.0` and treat the coordinates as points.

Comment: Great answer! Didn't try it tho, but I'll accept this as a more up to date answer than mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question since I figured it out some time ago.
You should make a retina aware context. The jaggedness only appeared on a retina device.

To counter this behavior, you should create a retina context with this helper method:

```
// Begin a graphics context for retina or SD
void RetinaAwareUIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize size) 
{
    static CGFloat scale = -1.0;

    if(scale < 0.0) 
    {   
        UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];

        if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 4.0)
        {    
            scale = [screen scale]; // Retina
        }
        else 
        {
            scale = 0.0; // SD
        }
    }

    if(scale > 0.0)
    {    
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, scale);   
    }
    else 
    {    
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);   
    }
}
```

Then, in your drawing method call the method listed above like so:

```
+ (CGLayerRef)standardCellBackgroundLayer
{
    static CGLayerRef standardCellBackgroundLayer;

    if(standardCellBackgroundLayer == NULL)
    {
        RetinaAwareUIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0));
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width, PLACES_DEFAULT_CELL_HEIGHT);

        ...
```

Comment: Hey @bitshiftcop, I tried your answer, but it is not working, I dont see  any drawing rendered. Can you help me out with this.